# Prevent Travis deploying multiple times when I'm running my tests on multiple Node versions?

Tags: travis-ci

I test on three different Node versions (mainly to alert me to any compatibility issues that might arise if I was forced to switch to another version in production):

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
node_js:
  - iojs
  - '0.12'
  - '0.10'
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: ./deploy.sh
  on:
    branch: master
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - node_js: iojs
```

But that means my `./deploy.sh` script is run three times, from three different containers! I obviously only want **one** of the successful builds to be deployed. The other builds are just for catching Node issues.

Is there a way to configure it so it only runs my deploy script after *one* of the jobs? Maybe another setting under `on:`?

The docs for [script provider](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/script/) don't cover this.

Answer (score 7):

What about setting a `node: '0.10'` option under `on:`? Like so:

```
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: ./deploy.sh
  on:
    branch: master
    node: '0.10'
```

This should run the deploy job only on the `node: '0.10'` target.

From the [Travis Deployment official docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Conditional-Releases-with-on%3A):

> `jdk`, `node`, `perl`, `php`, `python`, `ruby`, `scala`, `go`: For language runtimes
>   that support multiple versions, you can *limit the deployment to happen
>   only on the job that matches the desired version*.

Comment: Great advice, that works as expected and only deploy once, despite having multiple node targets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [conditional release](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Conditional-Releases-with-on%3A).